# Cannot find module 'expo/bundleNativeModules.json'

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using expo to build an app. I'm new to React-Native and expo so if you could help me, I'd be really appreciated.
I get a couple of warnings that says:

```
Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently installed expo package version
- expo-constants - expected version range: ...
- expo-permissions - expected version range: ...
- react-native-gesture-handler - expected version range: ...

Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
```

I was facing another error:

> "TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_styles.default.list')".

So I'm trying to install the latest version.

When I try to install `expo install expo-permissions` and `expo install react-native-gesture-handler`, I get errors.
Both errors say

> Cannot find module 'expo/bundledNativeModules.json'
>   Require stack:
>   - /Users/address/src/react-native-udacicards/noop.js

I tried to remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then `npm install`.

Comment: Where are you running the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rollback with npm install -g expo-cli@2.4.3

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution will work for all the situations, but this is what fixed the issue it for me:

1. clean the npm cache using the following command : npm cache clean --force
2. re-install the dependencies : npm install
3. expo install

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1.on your package.json change expo version to

- `"expo": "~43.0.2"`,  (or lower)
  and your `react-native-gesture-handler` to
- `"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2"`,
  (for expo 43.0.2)

2. Then, on your terminal (in your project), run

- `npm cache clean --force`
- `npm install`
- `expo doctor --fix-dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue but `Enableing USB tethering` in phone, and `clearing all data in expo` app resolved this issue.